# Photoshop: Crop tool displays CM and not Inches?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Just been using the crop tool and selecting "W x H x Resolution" but the resolution box is displaying px/cm and not px/inches.

I did a RESET tool but still it displays in px/cm.

I also noticed in the preferences under Units it was set to Centimeter, I am based in europe, is this why by default it is set to centimeter as a tutorial I was following did the exact same but their default was px/inches in the crop tool.

Would it be recommended to change this unit measure under the preferences ?

Comment: If you need inches sure. you can allways change it whenever you need.

Comment: If you are working in print, leave it in cm/in.  If you are working for screens, set it to px.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1. It is possible to toggle between px/in and px/cm
2. To toggle click on px/in or px/cm

Also please refer the image

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it in photoshop preferences ie in CC click in the top toolbar menu: Photoshop CC > Preferences > Units & Rulers

Comment: I think OP already knows where / how - their question was more around *whether* they should reset their units from the European SI to Imperial units...